# Rearding OpenSSL connection

Tags: command-line, openssl, syslinux, user-mode-linux

Once i connect to a server using command
Openssl s_client -quiet -connect ircs.overthewire. org:6697
What to do after I m connected
It shows cursor on line in which I can type anything?

Comment: Use an actual IRC client, not `openssl s_client`.  THat's only good to see the SSL handshake, really, of the connection, not to actually interact with a service.

Answer (score 3):

`openssl s_client` is basically the SSL version of netcat. You can use it to set up a SSL/TLS connection to a server, and then send the protocol data. As you're connecting to a IRC server by the looks of the command, you'd have to send [IRC protocol Commands](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812).

But this is probably not what you want. You probably want to use a IRC client to connect to the IRC server. Suggested IRC clients are hexchat, irssi, and many others.